# Using Pandas to apply a groupby aggregate to the original data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to do something that seems pretty easy in a spreadsheet but I can't figure the syntax in pandas. I have a data set that can be grouped. I want to determine the aggregate stats for each of the groups, but then use the aggregates to create a new column back in the original data frame.

For example, if my data frame looks like this:

```
d = pandas.dataframe({'class', : ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f1'], 
'user': ['jack', 'jen', 'joe', 'jan'], 
'screen': [12, 23, 13, 15] })
```

## yes its much smaller than my data set

I would like to do something like

```
d['gp'] = d['screen'].apply(d.groupby('class').stdev())
```

and assure that the d.groupby().stdev() is actually the stdev for that class for the row. In other words I don't want the stdev for class f1 to be used when calculating the gp for class f2, etc.

My brain is thinking in spreadsheet mode, or in a python for loop. I know there must be a simple pandas syntax to do this -- but so far I haven't found anything in my searches that seem to fit my use case.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same length as original `Dataframe`:

```
d['gp'] = d.groupby('class')['screen'].transform('std')
print (d)
  class  screen  user       gp
0    f1      12  jack  2.12132
1    f2      23   jen      NaN
2    f3      13   joe      NaN
3    f1      15   jan  2.12132
```

You get `NaN`s, because some groups (`f2`, `f3`) have length equal 1.

Comment: Exactly. I had the same letter my letter

Comment: not quite. I need the aggregate operations to be applied to the original data frame. but each agreegate op (mean, std dev) must be calculated for each group -- thus the group by

Comment: Do you need `d['screengrade']=d.groupby('class')['screen'].transform(lambda x: x / (x.std() + x.mean()) * 200 )` ? I am on phone only, so untested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this a little more and want to be a little more precise in defining what I want here. In my data set I have 3 groups of classes. I want to determine aggregate stats for each class; mean, std dev. So if I were doing this in pythonish pseudo code on a dict-list it would look something like this:

groupamean = mean(list of groupa['screens'])
groupastddev = stddev(list of groupa['screens'])

for p in groupa:
   x.append = groupa['screens'] * groupamean + groupastdev

This would be repeated for each group. This is the way plain python leads me to think.

Pandas with the data frame object invites a new way to think. Its nice to not have to use for loops to do things over a series. But I don't know how to assure that when I apply the aggregate functions produced by groupby, that I get the correct groups.

The syntax that seems to get close is this

```
d['screengrade']= d['Screens Typed'].apply(lambda x: x / (classgroups.std + classgroups.mean) * 200 )
```

But this throws a TypeError.

Comment: getting closer as the TypeError was thrown becuase classgroups.std is a function and I should have called it --